# Python - potential hardcoded secrets detected in repository

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am getting build failure saying "potential hardcoded secrets detected in your repository". If you see, i am placing JSON file in my python project root folder and accessing it here like this in my python script which is giving me hard coded secrets error. Where can i place this GCP service account JSON file so as to get rid of this error or is there any other way, please help

Here is my code -

```
def get_credentials(env):
    try:
        if env == 'stg':
            credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('stg.json')
        elif env == 'prod':
            credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('prod.json')
        
        return credentials
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        logging.info(e)


def get_secret(project_id, id, version_id):
    print("this is get_secret method")
    """gets secrets from gcp secret manager
    Args:
        project_id (str): coming from config.json
        id (str): coming from config.json
        version_id (str): latest
    Returns:
        str: secret value
    """
    try:
        client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient(credentials = get_credentials(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
        name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{id}/versions/{version_id}"  # Build the resource name of the secret version.
        response = client.access_secret_version(name=name)  # Access the secret version.
        secret = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
        return secret
            
    except Exception as e:
        # logger.error(f"Secrets are not fetched due to {e}")
        print(e)
        raise
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear: don't keep credentials in your repo, ever.

Give the entity (eg. VM) running this code the privileges to access the secret manager instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but i am not sure how to give permission

Comment: Then perhaps you'll google for the suitable method for wherever you'd deploy the code. You haven't told us where that is in particular.